# hosting multiple web apps using the istio ingress gateway

Tags: istio, istio-sidecar

We are using istio as a service mesh to secure our cluster. We have several web applications exposed through the ingress gateway as follows ingress-gateway-id:80/app1/, ingress-gateway-id:80/app2/ and ingress-gateway-id:80/app3/.

We have a gateway that routes traffic of the ingress gateway on port 80.

For each application, we create a virtual service that routes the traffic from (for example) ingress-gateway-id:80/app1/app1-api-uri/ to app1-service/app1-api-uri/

The main issue we are currently facing is that some applications work by only / (for example) app2-service/ which forces us to allow / through the virtual service and restrict the ingress gateway to allow only one application through the ingress gateway (without specifying hosts in headers as all our applications are web apps therefore accessible through a browser in our use case).

My question is how to allow multiple applications to access / through my ingress gateway (on the same port 80 for example) without the need to deal with setting host headers from the client (in our case the browser)?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use your domains as a virtual service hosts I would say the only options here would be to

- use rewrite in your virtual service.
- use custom headers

There is an example about rewrite from istio documentation.

> **HTTPRewrite**
>
> HTTPRewrite can be used to rewrite specific parts of a HTTP request before forwarding the request to the destination. Rewrite primitive can be used only with HTTPRouteDestination. The following example demonstrates how to rewrite the URL prefix for api call (/ratings) to ratings service before making the actual API call.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: ratings-route
spec:
  hosts:
  - ratings.prod.svc.cluster.local
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /ratings
    rewrite:
      uri: /v1/bookRatings
    route:
    - destination:
        host: ratings.prod.svc.cluster.local
        subset: v1
```

---

There is an example for 2 nginx deployments, both serving on `/`.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: nginx1
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: nginx1
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx1
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hello nginx1 > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html"]



---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx2
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: nginx2
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: nginx2
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx2
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hello nginx2 > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html"]

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: frontend
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: frontend


---

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: comp-ingress-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - hosts:
    - '*'
    port:
      name: http
      number: 80
      protocol: HTTP

---

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: nginxvirt
spec:
  gateways:
  - comp-ingress-gateway
  hosts:
  - '*'
  http:
  - name: match
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /a
    rewrite:
      uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
        subset: v1
        port:
          number: 80
  - name: default
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /b
    rewrite:
      uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
        subset: v2
        port:
          number: 80
---


apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: nginxdest
spec:
  host: nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      run: nginx1
  - name: v2
    labels:
      run: nginx2
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
```

And a test with curl.

```
curl -v xx.xxx.xxx.x/a 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Hello nginx1


curl -v xx.xxx.xxx.x/b
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Hello nginx2
```

---

There is an [example](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/request-routing/#route-based-on-user-identity) about custom headers in istio documentation.

Comment: Thanks Jakub. The problem i am facing with my frontend apps is the redirects. I am using some technologies (apache atlas) and  i would like to reroute to its UIs. The flow goes as follow: 1. ingress-gateway/atlas -> gets redirected to an Oauth provided to login -> which gets redirects to atlas on "/" after login. Therefore, i get "/" after login. I need to use the prefix "/" to reroute to different applications on the same gateway which is probably not possible. The solution you proposed assumed that apache atlas will redirect to ingress-gateway/atlas in order to access the / of atlas.